# jquery datatables: adding extra column

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datatables, customization

**Scenario**

I am using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) (@version 1.9.4) for the first time to display data to the user.
I succeed in retrieving the data via ajax and in binding them to the datatable.

Now I want to add extra columns to let the user process the records. For semplicity sake, the aim is to add a button with an onclick handler that retrieve the data of the 'clicked' record.

In my plan I would bind the json item corresponding to the 'clicked' record to the onclick handler.

Till now, if I add an additional `TH` for the action column to the DOM, an error occurs from datatables code:

```
Requested unknown parameter '5' from data source for row 0
```

**Question**

How to set custom columns? How to fill their content with HTML?

---

Here is my actual config.

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableCities">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>zip</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>district code</th>
            <th>district description</th>
            <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#tableCities').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true
    , "bJQueryUI": true
    , "bProcessing": true
    , "bServerSide": true
    , "sAjaxSource": "../biz/GetCitiesByZip.asp?t=" + t
});
```

**Sample Json result**

```
{
    "aaData":
    [
        [
            "IT",
            "10030",
            "VILLAREGGIA",
            "TO",
            "Torino"
        ],
        [
            "IT",
            "10030",
            "VISCHE",
            "TO",
            "Torino"
        ]
    ],
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "iDisplayLength": 2
}
```

**Edit**

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617373/daniel) is right. The solution is to set up the custom column in the `aoColumnDefs`, specifying the `mData` and the `mRender` properties. In particular [`mRender`](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) lets to define custom html and javascript.

```
/* inside datatable initialization */
, "aoColumnDefs": [
   {
        "aTargets": [5],
        "mData": null,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\''+ full[0] +'\');">Process</a>';
        }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: it's works for me, +1 for additional html link/button on each row complete with 'get the row id value'.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can define your columns in a different way
like this

```
"aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "mData": null }
    ]
```

or this

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
    {
        "aTargets":[5],
        "mData": null
    }
]
```

Here some docs [Columns](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Take a look at this [DataTables AJAX source example - null data source for a column](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

> Note that prior to DataTables 1.9.2 mData was called mDataProp. The name change reflects the flexibility of this property and is consistent with the naming of mRender. If 'mDataProp' is given, then it will still be used by DataTables, as it automatically maps the old name to the new if required.

Another solution/workaround could be adding that '5' parameter...

For example adding extra `""` to each row

like this:

```
    [
        "IT",
        "10030",
        "VILLAREGGIA",
        "TO",
        "Torino",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "IT",
        "10030",
        "VISCHE",
        "TO",
        "Torino",
        ""
    ]
```

Comment: Straightforward, the 5th missing parameter just corresponds to the action column. To add an _empty_ field to the data source seems to be a workaround rather then an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone using a newer version of DataTables (1.10+) is looking for an answer to this question, I followed the directions on this page:

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

Comment: Yup. Use "defaultContent"

Answer (score 6):

Posting this answer here, just to show that where the `aoColumnDefs` needs to be defined. I got help from this question it self, but I struggled for a while for where to put the `aoColumnDefs`.  Further more also added the functionality for onclick event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#userTable').DataTable( {
        "sAjaxSource": "/MyApp/proctoring/user/getAll",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "users",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "username" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "surname" },
                    { "data": "status" },
                    { "data": "emailAddress" },
                    { "data" : "userId" }
                  ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
           {
                "aTargets": [5],
                "mData": "userId",
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<button href="#"' + 'id="'+ data + '">Edit</button>';
                }
            }
         ]
    } );

    $('#userTable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        console.log(data);
        $('#userEditModal').modal('show');
    });

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Action**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Roles()
        {
            var data = _accountService.GetRoles().Result;
            return Json(data);
        }
```

**CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" /> 
 <script
 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

**Html**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th></th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
              </table>
```

**DataTable Code**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            debugger;
            $("#table").dataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Admistration/Roles",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataSrc": "",
                     "datatype": "json"
                },
               "columns": [
                    { "data": "code", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": 'name', "autoWidth":true},
                    { "render": function (data, type, full) { return "<a  class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + full.code + "') ><i class='bi bi-trash3-fill'></i></a>   <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + full.code + "'); ><i class='bi bi-pencil-square'></i></a>" } }
                ]
            });
        })
   
    </script>
```