# DataTables extra column with button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables.

### Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').dataTable( {
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                    "url": "../server_processing/orders.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                    },
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "processing": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [            
                {
                    "aTargets": [ 0 ], 
                    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                        return '<a href="order?id=' + full[0] + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                        return '<a href=\'view.php?id=\'' + full[0] + '\' class=\'btn btn-primary\'>View</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

I want to add an extra column at the end and each row has a button:

```
<a href="view.php?id=XXXXXX" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Sales</a>
```

The `XXXXXX` should be the contents of row 1.

Is it possible?

Comment: I had the same problem. Have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/13231758/1083946](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13231758/1083946).

Answer (score 1):

Without any code I can only guess at your table initialisation and datatables version, but using 1.9 you can do this:

```
'aoColumns': [
{
  'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
     return '<a href=\'view.php?id=\'' + full[0] + '\' class=\'btn btn-primary\'>Contact Sales</a>';
}
```

`full[0]` is the value returned in the first field of your json data.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to paste code!  I updated it,  I did try your answer but I don't get an extra column added?

Comment: Have you added an extra column `<th>` in the HTML? You could try `aoColumns` instead of `aoColumnDefs`

Answer (score 0):

I did it with jQuery's .append .

To make sure that the click event is binded to the button (pagination) I used **$(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function (e){ ... });** instead of usual **$('.btn-primary').on('click', function (e) { ... });** .

I disabled sorting on that column. As far as I can see a content of the cell might as well be a valid renderable HTML, you just disable sorting. It might cause some problems with filtering but you can make your own filter function in DataTables.